# how can be possible to programmatically upload and retrieve photos from PicasaWeb in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, picasa

Is it possible to use PicasaWeb to host photos for my website? My requirement to upload and access within my ASP.NET Website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, technically. You can use the Pic[asa Web Albums Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html) to access the metadata about your images and then display them from Picasa. For an album, this is not a horrible idea, but I would not use this method for your site graphics.

Comment: What my findings is that, if I upload image using filestream, it works fine, but not works with memorystream.  Therefore, I copied uploaded file at temp location and created filestream and uploaded to picasa.  Then removed file from temp location.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public string UploadImage(byte[] imageBytes_, string imageName_)
    {
        string url = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            PicasaEntry newPhoto = null;
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(imageBytes_, 0, imageBytes_.Length);
            if (_albumFeed != null)
            {
                PicasaEntry photoEntry = new PhotoEntry();
                photoEntry.MediaSource = new Google.GData.Client.MediaFileSource(ms, imageName_, "image/jpeg");

                newPhoto = this._service.Insert<PicasaEntry>(new Uri(this._albumFeed.Post), photoEntry);
            }

            url = newPhoto.FeedUri;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new DneException("Error while uploading photo", ex );
        }

        return url ;
    }
```

I am uploading a zipped images and extracting using SharpZipLib library. I am getting each file in chunk of bytes and which I am converting into MemoryStream later to pass the MediaSource object.  I am getting 400 Bad Request error each time.  When I am passing FileStream, it works fine but doesn't work with MemoryStream